# Not able to listen mousemove event inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In the web page document, I am trying to fetch the control information when ever i move the mouse pointer over the control  using "mousemove" event handler. I am able to get the control information for the main page document except for the controls inside "iframe". PFB code

```
**function OnMouseMove (event) 
{
 var ele=document.elementFromPoint (posX, posY);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove',OnMouseMove,true);**
```

so for "iframes" I tried below approach but of no result.Since I don't have any info regarding the content i tried using tagname but it is not working as expected.

```
**document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").contentWindow.document.OnMouseMove = OnMouseMove;**
```

*Please help me how to fetch the control information inside an iframe when there are no control attributes available during mouse hover*.

Comment: is the iframe in the same origin? `Since I don't have any info regarding the content` - I'm guessing, no

Comment: No , iframe is not in the same origin. Even the iframe is in the same origin i am not able to listen the event handler inside iframe

Comment: Then you have no chance at all. It's called security

Answer (score 0):

You can do that quite easily if the document in the iframe is on the same document.domain.

Put `pointer-events: none` in the styles for the frame.

Comment: I have cases like iframe can be in the same domain and the other case is iframe is not in the same domain. so the answer you have suggested is not applicable for cross domain.